# MDX calculated measure slow when adding operations

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

I have created a calculated measure through BIDS in a SSAS cube and it's like the following:

```
IIF([Measures].[RatePct] >= 0.90, [Measures].[measureA],  [Measures].[measureB])
```

The point is that if I convert the above to this:

```
IIF([Measures].[RatePct] >= 0.90, [Measures].[measureA],  0)
```

or that:

```
IIF([Measures].[RatePct] >= 0.90, [Measures].[measureA] + 100,  [Measures].[measureB])
```

the measure becomes extremely slow when using it in the cube.

Any ideas why this is happening and how can it be addressed?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because in both cases you are returning values that were earlier a possible null. Now the number of empty combinations have decreaded. Consider a case where [Measures].[measureA] was null but since you now have [Measures].[measureA] + 100 this will return 100 as a value. Now you UI will not be able to remove it as a null combination

Comment: Thanks! it's pretty much that. I managed though to make it quick with the below workaround:  
[Measures].[measureA] + 100*([Measures].[measureA]/[Measures].[measureA]) 

Now, it became very fast...

Comment: You are welcome. You might want to consider marking my suggestion as answer